# AngularJS vs React - adoption rate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I am currently evaluating [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) for company usage. To find valid arguments to choose one over the other seems difficult, since a lot of arguments in the field are *primary opinion based*. That is why, I am trying to find another angle to make a decision and look at **the general adoption of each framework**.

So, here my question: **who of the major and medium players *out there* is verifiably using either framework for their main web presence?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour Don't ask about... Product or service recommendations or comparisons , Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.

Comment: Imo there is no point in comparing those two. `AngularJS` is a web application framework which covers much more than `React` does. React is a UI-library. You could even combine those two. For writing the UI I prefer React because of the clear data flow (no watchers, no two way binding). But how does it help you with your decision by knowing who uses them? There are big companies/apps on both "sides" and both are supported/documented very well.

Comment: Not to mention that due to Non Disclosure Agreements it's highly improbable that you will get answers like ...."I work for XYZ Inc. and here's a list of the technologies we use...."

Comment: @fuubah right you are - I know this question is close to a Stackoverflow convention infringement. Still, this is a hot topic at the moment and a couple of good answers could help the community a great deal.

Comment: @FlorianGl How does it help to know what is used by others? Checking out the adopter's web presence would give me the chance to evaluate whether there are common use cases better suited to one or the other framework. This knowledge I can then apply to my own use case.

Comment: @charlietfl A lot of companies are very outspoken about their stack, e.g. http://techblog.netflix.com/2015/01/netflix-likes-react.html

Comment: Fritz, I know it is a hot topic, but if you search on stack overflow you can see that several people have asked the same and the discussion has been done several times. I agree with Florian here, but I will say one thing. React is more fun. That is my own opinion after working with both.

Comment: FWIW: https://github.com/facebook/react/wiki/Sites-Using-React